# natbib with Vancouver bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, external-files

I'm write a document of type **tufte-handout**, and wanted to use *Vancouver* reference style for bibliography, however I get the following error:

> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

This doesn't stop the document from generating, and references are also created fine, but they use *plane* bib style. How can I stop this error from occurring, and what does it actually mean? Is there a way to force *Vancouver* style?

**EDIT:** Added MVE. I should also mention I'm using BasicTeX.
Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] \cite{Lucas:2006}

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\nobibliography{test-refs}

\end{document}
```

Content of bib file:

```
@inbook{Lucas:2006,
Author = {Adam Lucas},
Date-Added = {2016-03-01 22:05:32 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-03-01 22:05:32 +0000},
Number = {90-04-14649-0},
Pages = {65},
Publisher = {Brill Publishers},
Title = {Wind, Water, Work: Ancient and Medieval Milling Technology},
Year = {2006}}
```

Comment: Please show us the exact code with which you load the `natbib` package and specify the bibliography style.

Comment: @Mico I don't load the `natbib` myself. However, I've added code for minimum verifiable example. Thanks @egreg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `natbib` package is being loaded with the option `authoryear`. In contrast, the `vancouver` bibliography style is designed to generate numeric-style rather than authoryear-style citation call-outs. To enable this behavior, it is necessary to override the default setting. This may be accomplished by issuing the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{numbers}
```

after the `\documentclass` instruction.

Comment: Using a new example project from ShareLatex, if I set `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}` and add `\setcitestyle{numbers}` just after `\usepackage{natbib}`, I get an error due to the presence of `  url={whatever},` in an entry of `bib` file.

Comment: @mmj - Your issue is completely unrelated to the `natbib` package or the `vancouver` style. To use the `\url` macro, the `url` and/or the `hyperref` packages must be loaded. Is this the case in your document?

Comment: Actually no, but I get no error if I use `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{plain}` (however the `url` field of the `bib` entry is unused).

Comment: @mmj - The reason you get no url-related error message if you use the `plain`  bibliography style is yet a separate matter: The `plain` style simply ignores a field named `url`! In contrast, the `vancouver` style does *not* ignore such a field. However, in order to typeset the contents of the `url` field properly, the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages must be loaded by your document, since a macro named `\url` must be available. Is there a (valid!) reason for being reluctant to load these packages?

Comment: No reluctance of course, I'll load `hyperref`, just wanted to understand why before I got no error. Thanks!

Comment: @mmj - If you're motivated, feel free to peruse the code in the file `vancouver.bst`, starting at line 1379. There, you'll find a BibTeX function called `format.url`; it includes a couple of instances of `\url{...}`.